# writing or reading a file based on a if statement

Tags: python-3.x, file

I'm writing a script that will either run a program if a text file doesn't contain something and do nothing if it does. It keeps on running the program and stead of doing nothing even though the text file does contain the thing that it's looking for.

here's my code:

```py
my_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
path = os.path.join(my_path, "../etc/4532/7.txt")
checkw = open(path, "w+")
print(checkw.read())
if 'boot-state=True' in checkw.read():
    print("status: True")
    checkw.close()
else:
    print(checkw)
    print("sys:booting into img LOADER")
    os.system("~/master/root/xf10/__img-builder/./set.py")
    checkw.write("boot-state=True")
```

Thank you, in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems here:

1. You open your file in mode `w+`. This overwrites your file if it exists. If you want to read the existing file, use `r` or `r+`.
2. Your `print` call on line 4 moves the pointer to the end of the file. The next read call will therefore return nothing. Try removing the print or call `checkw.seek(0,0)` to move back to the beginning of the file.

Comment: I tried this and it still did the same thing it wouldn't see that there was the text it was looking for

Comment: what do you mean debugging?